Homotopy equivalent but non-homeomorphic high-dimensional manifolds
I have a question motivated by the classification theory of simply-connected closed $4$-manifolds.
Questions: Given any $n\geq 5$, is it possible to find two simply-connected closed $n$-manifolds $M$ and $N$, such that $M$ and $N$ are homotopy equivalent but non-homeomorphic? Furthermore, can it be further stated that one of them admits a smooth structure while the other does not?

I will answer the first question on the existence of closed simply-connected manifolds that are homotopy equivalent but not homeomorphic.
No such example exists in dimension 5. Closed simply-connected $5$-manifolds are classified, and moreover, the homotopy, homeomorphism and diffeomorphism classification all coincide. See in Manifold atlas or in
[D. Barden, Simply connected five-manifolds, Ann. of Math. (2) 82 (1965), 365–385].
Note that any closed simply-connected $5$-manifold $M^5$ has a smooth structure because any PL manifold of dimension $\le 7$ is smoothable, and the only obstruction to the existence of a PL structure is the Kirby-Siebenmann class that lies in $H^4(M^5;\mathbb Z_2)\cong H_1(M^5;\mathbb Z_2)=0$ by Poincare duality and simply-connectedness.
In dimension $n\ge 6$ there is a closed manifold that is homotopy equivalent but not homeomorphic to $S^4\times S^{n-4}$. The manifold is produced by surgery (in particular, I think it can be chosen smooth).
These matters are extensively discussed in On the cardinality of the manifold set by Crowley and Macko. For example, their theorem 3.1 says that if $M$ is a closed simply-connected topological $n$-manifold with $n\ge 5$, then the set of homeomorphism classes of closed manifolds in the homotopy type of $M$ is infinite if and only if
$H^{4i}(M,\mathbb Q)\neq 0$ for some integer $i$ with $0<4i<n$. This applies to $M=S^4\times S^{n-4}$, $n\ge 6$ as I mentioned above.

There is a nice algebro-geometric example in dimension 6 in Libgober-Wood, Topology 21, no. 4, pp. 469-482 (1982). They consider smooth complete intersections $X\subset \mathbb{P}^8$ of degrees (2,3, 3, 14, 15) and $Y\subset \mathbb{P}^7$ of degrees (5,6, 7, 18). They show that they are homotopy equivalent but that they have different first Pontryagin class, hence they are not homeomorphic.

Given that there are so many homotopy equivalent non-homeomorphic simply-connected manifolds, it is no surprise that they come up in geometry. For example, there are compact homogeneous spaces with the property. It is trickier however to produce geometric examples in EVERY dimension $\ge 6$. Is this possible for smooth complete intersections?
